# ng-show does not work with checkbox switch

Tags: angularjs

I am using a checkbox switch that is based on the bootstrap switch (documentation here: https://tictail.com/developers/documentation/uikit/#Switches).

I want to use ng-show on an element just like in the example here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

However nothing happens when I click on the switch (check the checkbox tied to the switch).

I used an existing plunker to put the issue in the right context:
http://embed.plnkr.co/LRSGXqxjtbYcr6rjTj69/

HTML:

```
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Test switch</legend>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="testSwitch">Test switch</label><br>
    <div class="switch" init-switch>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="testSwitch">
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset ng-show="testSwitch">
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you wanna show and hide? because the only thing I can see is a fieldset with a label and checkbox.

Comment: If you are talking about the checkbox in contact/help, its working fine.

Comment: your fancy switch is not switching at all please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/VaqEOLhJMVa4jvCmqKx8?p=preview

Comment: @sss is right - swith toggling is done via jQuery, outside angular context so it will not work. You can : 1. get rid of this fancy switch 2. Hack js lib and add scope.$apply in proper place 3. Find other UI toolkit that is angular friendly

Comment: @MiTa - The second option is the only way to go for me then, because I am forced in this project to use the fancy switch and that particular UI toolkit. I would really appreciate any suggested solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please bear in mind that I'm very new to Angular so this might not be the best answer.

I think whatever the Switch plugin is doing is preventing the value on the checkbox to be changed (or propagated to angular).

What I think you can do is on your directive, bind something to the change event, and use an isolate scope on the directive to do two way binding with the variable from the controler.

HTML:

```
<div class="switch" init-switch switch-variable="testSwitch">
   <input type="checkbox" id="check">
</div>
```

The switch-variable will do the 2-way-binding with the directive

Directive:

```
app.directive('initSwitch', function () {
        return {
            scope: {
              switchVariable: '=' //this is how you define 2way binding with whatever is passed on the switch-variable attribute
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                scope.$evalAsync(function () {
                    element.switch();
                });

                element.on("change", function(){
                   if(scope.switchVariable)
                    scope.switchVariable = !scope.switchVariable
                   else
                    scope.switchVariable = true;

                   scope.$apply(); //I believe you need this to propagate the changes
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

---

Edit:

As per your first comment, can you try changing the directive event to:

```
element.on("change", function(){
   if(element.children('.switch-off')[0]) //Looking for the class that determines to what side the switch is
     scope.switchVariable = false;
   else
     scope.switchVariable = true;
   scope.$apply(); //I believe you need this to propagate the changes
});
```

As for your second point, if you set the checkbox to checked, then your link function needs to know the state of the checkbox:

```
scope.$evalAsync(function () {
  scope.switchVariable = element.children()[0].checked; //check if checkbox is checked (before the plugin changes the DOM

  element.switch(); //initialize the plugin
});
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Seems that sometimes if I click very fast it ends up "reversed" so the ng-show is true even though the switch is set to "no". Any ideas why that happens?

Comment: Also I noticed that if I set the checkbox to checked on load like <input type="checkbox" checked> the switch will be set to "yes" but the ng-show will be false and if I bind another regular checkbox to keep track of what is really happening with the switch, it is not checked. So it seems it only works if I click the switch, and not too fast.

Comment: Running into a problem with the switch again when I get the checkbox value (true/false) from JSON-data in a http GET. I use ng-checked="formData.active" on the checkbox itself instead of as before hardcoding it to <input type="checkbox" checked>. Any ideas on how to make that work? Is it a matter of the switch not "listening" for values?

Comment: Started a new question for some more issues with the switch. Hope you can help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018123/checkbox-switch-not-listening

Answer (score 2):

You have to nest your code within the ng-app so that it knows it's an angular app.

```
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Test switch</legend>
            <div class="form-group" >
                <label for="testSwitch">Test switch</label><br>
                <div class="switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="testSwitch"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <h1 ng-show="testSwitch">Now you see me</h1>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/df1gz8jk/1/

Comment: There is `ng-app='myApp'` 3rd line in `index.html`