# Checkbox Switch not listening

Tags: angularjs

I am using checkbox switches in my AngularJS app. They are dependent on jQuery and obviously not perfect for Angular, but I am forced to use this UIKit in which they are included.

Thanks to help from people on this site I have found a semi working solution, but there is still something missing to get the switch listening to the current value of the actual checkbox.

I have put an example in an existing plunker. You'll find it on "Contact & Help" (help.html) and the controller name is HelpController.

What I am trying to do now is set the value of the checkbox/switch to "true" from the JS so I could load the saved state of the checkbox/switch from a database.

Any ideas on how to solve it? Thanks!

**Plunker:**
http://embed.plnkr.co/LRSGXqxjtbYcr6rjTj69/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments:

On your controller you would get the initial setting for the checkbox:

```
app.controller('HelpController', function ($scope) {

   $scope.theCheckbox = true; //in here you would set theCheckbox variable from your DB

   ....

 });
```

Then you pass the initial value to the directive, pay attention to the attribute name `switch-variable` (it will be Camel case on the directive):

```
<div class="switch" init-switch switch-variable="theCheckbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="active" name="active">
</div>
```

And then finally on the directive:

```
 scope.$evalAsync(function () {
   element.switch(); //initialize the plugin
   if(scope.switchVariable)
      element.switch("toggleState");
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, now it listens to the initial state, but if I change the checkbox with ng-model="theCheckbox", the switch still stays unchanged. Check the updated plunker (with your new solution): http://embed.plnkr.co/LRSGXqxjtbYcr6rjTj69/

Comment: Why do you need to use ng-model?

Comment: I mean another checkbox that I added just to be able to change the state from a different place after the page has loaded. Is it possible to bind the switch with the ng-model of another element?

Comment: Best way is to $watch the variable in your directive: `scope.$watch("switchVariable", function(newValue, oldValue){if(newValue!==oldValue) element.switch("toggleState");});` here's the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/rIUa1N7TiWq7xFjKYrET

Comment: I also get this error onload and then the same error several hundred times (like 469 times) when I try to click the switch (which works but is very slow): https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest - and this: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
"

Comment: Any ideas about the error? It works pretty good, except that the animation gets really slow when you click the switch itself and it generates a large amount of errors. Really stuck here.

Comment: it seems the $watch bit is triggering the change event, and the change event is triggering the $watch bit. See what I changed here http://plnkr.co/edit/NqSov4LnGg0Npg5n8Zr3?p=preview

Comment: Brilliant! Lets hope this was the last piece of the switch-puzzle! Many thanks!

Comment: The documentation says that you can pass a second argument to ToggleState which prevents it from triggering the change event, but that didn't seem to work